# Reactjs how to toggle a class on inactive route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my very first reactjs app (long time Angular dev wanting to see what the other side is like).  I want to add a "hollow" class on the inactive link.  I'm using `react-router-dom`.  Here is my simple menu:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div className="button-group no-gaps">
            <NavLink to="/work-items"><a className="button">Work Items</a></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/settings"><a className="button">Settings</a></NavLink>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

How would i got about doing that?  I see the react-router-dom has an activeClassName property on NavLink but not an inactiveClassName property?

EDIT:
I want to dynammically add the "hollow" class on the inactiveRoute in the `<a>` inside the `<NavLink>`.  In the code below the workitems route is inactive.

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div className="button-group no-gaps">
            <NavLink to="/work-items"><a className="button hollow">Work Items</a></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/settings"><a className="button">Settings</a></NavLink>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

EDIT:
machineghost pointed me down the right path with useLocation hook.  Here is my working solution.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavLink, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';


const Menu = () => {

    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(()=> {
        console.log('Location Changed', location);
    }, [location]);

    return (
        <div className="button-group no-gaps">
            <NavLink
                to ="/work-items"
                className={`button ${location.pathname === '/work-items' ? '':'hollow'}`}
            >Work Items</NavLink>
            <NavLink
                to="/settings"
                className={`button ${location.pathname === '/settings' ? '':'hollow'}`}
            >Settings</NavLink>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it with plain old React, by using a state variable, eg.:

```
const Menu = () => {
    const [hasGaps, setHasGaps] = useState(false);
    // call setHasGaps(true/false) based on window.location
    return (
        <div className={`button-group ${hasGaps ? '' : 'no-gaps'}`}>
            <NavLink to="/work-items"><a className="button">Work Items</a></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/settings"><a className="button">Settings</a></NavLink>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But, it'd be more direct to instead use React Router's `useParams` hook, and base the class on one of your route parameters instead.

```
const Menu = () => {
    const { someParamInYourRoute } = useParams();
    return (
        <div className={`button-group ${someParamInYourRoute ? '' : 'no-gaps'}`}>
            <NavLink to="/work-items"><a className="button">Work Items</a></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/settings"><a className="button">Settings</a></NavLink>
        </div>
    );
}
```

P.S. If your logic isn't based on a param, there's also a `useLocation` hook that you use to get a `window.location`-like object that you can could similarly base your ternary on.

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution more elegant. Turns out inactiveClassName is className!

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavBar() {
    return (
        // Your own code here
        <NavLink className='inactive classes here' activeClassName='active classes here' to='/about'>About</NavLink>
    )
};

export default NavBar
```

No hooks needed

```
className=""
```

is applied always

```
activeClassName=""
```

is applied when active

So in the case of the original question use  with the following attributes:

```
className="button"

activeClassName="button hollow"
```

Comment: I don't think this is true, `className` is applied always, when active and inactive.